# action-on-google send tcp/ip message to a server

Tags: tcp, actions-on-google

I would like to create an action on google to send the spoken input of the user to a tcp/ip server. 
Now my question is if this is possible at the time? I see the tutorials for actions on google, but there are always only asking and response things. 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. You can't access the spoken input in any way. The user says something to the Assistant, the Assistant listens and turns it into a string of text of what it thinks it heard based on the language settings. It then sends this string in a JSON object to either the Actions on Google SDK or Dialogflow depending on what you're using. From there you can access and handle the input(with the addition of a webhook).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So then it should be possible to send a webhook to a raspberry pi for example. And then i can do the hole tcpip sending stuff on the PI?

Comment: I'm not familiar with tcpip, but from your webhook you could send something to a PI and then do whatever you want from it. Try updating your question to clarify what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: Rather than making comments trying to change what you're doing - can you update your question to give a clear example of what you're trying to accomplish and what possible ways you're trying to do it? As it stands now, your original question is vague, and this followup is even more vague. (Tho Bart's answer is spot-on.)